# Spline Loader for Nuxt

Tags: three.js, nuxt.js, spline

I'm trying to add some animations from Spline on my Nuxt (v2) Project.
On Spline, i export my animation to three.js files.

On my nuxt project, i installed three and Splinetool/loader:

```
"dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "@splinetool/loader": "^0.9.252",
    "three": "^0.150.1",
```

But when i try to import Spline Loader:

```
import SplineLoader from '@splinetool/loader';
```

I have this message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@splinetool/loader/build/SplineLoader.js 1:41167
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:41167)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I need a loader to load a loader...??
Thanks a lot ;)
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

it means that, in nuxt 2 spline loader is not supported. infact three js in nuxt is not supported to load spline's model. if you switch to react it may work without this issue.